# Understanding Makefile Syntax and Variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm reading a big Makefile, part of which I don't understand:

```
$(IREJECTION): $(IREJECTION:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)
        $(CPP) $(CPPDLIBOPTS) -c $(@:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp) -o $@
```

In this script (note that I removed unnecessary variables to avoid verbosity), what does the following mean

- `$(IREJECTION:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)`  (on the first line)
- `$(@:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)` ?         (on the second line)

Also, what does this form `A: B` mean? As in :

```
 $(IREJECTION): $(IREJECTION:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)   #on the first line
 <---- A ---->  <------------ B --------------->   #first instance of A: B
                <--- A ----> <-------- B ------>   #second instance of A: B
```

As you see, there are two instances of the form `A:B` — the second one is inside `B` itself. I see similar thing here as well:

```
$(@:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)   #on the second line
 <A> <---------B------->
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: these are substitituoin/rewrite rules: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs.  basically `$(var:%.foo=%.bar)` means replace `.foo` extensions of all elements of `var` with `.bar`

Comment: @Anycorn: I think you meant : **replace** `.bar` extensions of all elements of `var` **with** `.foo`?

Comment: I see why it would be confusion, but no, it is in that form

Comment: @Anycorn: So you mean, in `%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp`, `.cpp` files are being generated from `.o` files?

Comment: the dependencies are being generated from the target (.o) files.  I'll write a detailed answer.

Comment: @Anycorn: Alright, I'll read your answer first then ask further questions (if any). Take your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got quite complex example I think. It has many things in it.

## Rule / Recipe

```
A: B
    <command>
```

- `A` - target
- `B` - dependency
- `<command>` - command to be executed to build `A` ("Recipe")

`target: dependency` is called a 'rule'.
So all in all, above example is 'rule' with appropriate 'recipe'.

(to make `A`, which depends on `B`, one needs to execute `<command>`)

`make` compares modifications dates of `B` and `A`. If `B` is newer, then it executes `<command>`

## Variables

`$(IREJECTION)` is `make`'s variable (it should be defined somewhere before in the file, like `IREJECTION:=somefile.o`)

During `make` execution `$(IREJECTION)` is replaced to actual value of the variable.

## Variable substitution

From link below:

`$(var:a=b)` <..>  take the value of the variable `var`, replace every 'a' at the end of a word with 'b' in that value, and substitute the resulting string.

And:

For example:

```
 foo := a.o b.o c.o
 bar := $(foo:%.o=%.c)
```

sets `bar` to `a.c b.c c.c`.

In your case `$(IREJECTION:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)`, it takes variable named `IREJECTION`, tries to find `$(MACH64).o` (which also references variable `MACH64`) at the end of the word and replace it with `.cpp`.

## Automatic variable

`$@` is called automatic variable.
It is reference to the 'target'.

## Futher reading

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Actually, the target/dependency part is the _Rule_, and the shell commands are the _Recipe_. A target can appear in more than one Rule, but at most one of those Rules can have a Recipe.

Answer (score 2):

`A: B` meant that you add a make target A that depends on B. That means when B was changed, it has to be run before A is done.
You can use the target A by calling `make A`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go tep by step:

lets say you have some object file `irejection.mach64.o` and the source file `irejection.cpp`

to generate object from source you typically write a rule smth like

```
irejection.mach64.o : irejection.cpp # means target : dependencies
    $(CC) irejection.cpp -o $@ # $@ is a special variable - the target (output)
```

Now lets say `$(MACH64)` is `.mach64` and `$(IREJECTION)` is `irejection$(MACH64).o`, ie `irejection.mach64.o`

`$(IREJECTION:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)` will expand to `irejection.cpp`

`$(@:%$(MACH64).o=%.cpp)` will expand to the same, since `$@` is `$(IREJECTION)`

In essence, given object file target with a architecture extensions, rewrite the file name to its source file counterpart.

Seems unncessearily convoluted to me tho.  Cleaner way would be smth like:

```
%$(MACH64).o : %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $@ $<
```

`%` are "wildcards", `$<` is the first dependency, `$@` is the output

see: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules

Comment: Now I understand the *replace* thingy. It is in reverse direction which is a bit weird, because after replacement, the `cpp` file generated might not be the actual file (on disk) to be compiled. Anyway, in order for this to work, the object files should have exactly same *prefix* as the source files.

Comment: @Nawaz replace thingy is more of `transform foo to bar` rather than bar is foo`.  more generally some common root needs to exist for pattern rules to work

Comment: @Nawaz btw, when writing rule commands, always always always use TAB or you'll get strange errors.